# 500 Error to Ajax call in Asp.Net MVC project

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

A post request sent from ajax gets 500 error, although server sent response (saw in debugger). The response is set to the correct URL, and it gets executed by the server. The server return the result but in the browser the error status 500 is displayed.

This is for an ASP.net MVC small app.

```
    $(window).on("load", function () {
    console.log("LOADING");
    $.post("/Play/Word", {}, function (data) {
    console.log(data['content']);
});
```

This is in C#:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Word()
    {
        var assigned = Json(Assigned(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return assigned;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any error message to go with that 500 error?  If necessary, enable errors in your Web.config.  (Should be the default when debugging locally though.)  What is the content returned from the server?

Comment: Thank you. Enabled errors, seemed a circular reference in the serialization was the issue. Solved.